# Objective C - ImageView (custom checkmark) in UITableViewCell stops toggling after multiple cell selections

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I've encountered some very strange behaviour with my tableViewCells in a simple list application (iOS).

**This is the basic function of my working app  :**
TableView with 2 sections. First section (e.g. with 2 cells) is always visible. Second section can be shown/hidden with a custom button in the section header. I've created two classes (i.e. FirstSectionItem and SecondSectionItem) both with a boolean property "completed" and some other properties.

After compilations the app runs as expected. Tapping cells results in showing the checkmarks and tapping them again hides the checkmarks (=custom imageView). However after tapping some different cells (random order) or showing/hiding the second section the checkmark (ImageViews) tend to stay checked no matter how much I tap the cells. After a while every cell is checked and can't be unchecked but the boolean values still keep changing.

**Here's part of the code:**

```
@property NSMutableArray *sectionTitleArray;
@property NSMutableDictionary *sectionContentDict;
@property NSMutableArray *firstSectionItems;
@property NSMutableArray *secondSectionItems;
```

ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (!self.sectionTitleArray) {
        self.sectionTitleArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"section1", @"section2", nil];
    }

    self.firstSectionItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.secondSectionItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self loadInitialData];

    self.sectionContentDict  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    self.arraySection1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.firstSectionItems count]; i++)
         {
             FirstSectionItem *firstSectionItem = [self.firstSectionItem objectAtIndex:i];
             [self.arraySection1 addObject:firstSectionItem.itemName];
         }

     self.arraySection2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     for (int i = 0; i < [self.secondSectionItems count]; i++)
        {
             SecondSectionItem *secondSectionItem = [self.secondSectionItems objectAtIndex:i];
             [self.arrayFuture addObject:secondSectionItem.itemName];
        }

    [self.sectionContentDict setValue:self.arraySection1  forKey:[self.sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    [self.sectionContentDict setValue:self.arraySection2 forKey:[self.sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:1]];
}
```

CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListPrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     // ... cell content ...

     NSArray *content = [self.sectionContentDict valueForKey:[self.sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];

     //... constraints ...

     UIImage *checkmark = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark.png"];
     UIImage *noCheckmark = [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent.png"];
     UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

     if (indexPath.section==0){

          FirstSectionItem *firstSectionItem = [self.firstSectionItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
             imageView.image = firstSectionItem.completed ? checkmark : noCheckmark;

}


     if (indexPath.section==1){
        if(self.sec2isTapped == YES){
            SecondSectionItem *secondSectionItem = [self.secondSectionItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            imageView.image = secondSectionItem.completed ? checkmark : noCheckmark;
         }
      }

     [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

     // ... more constraints 


return cell;
}
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    if (indexPath.section ==0){
        FirstSectionItem *tappedItem = [self.firstSectionItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed;
    }
    if (indexPath.section ==1){
         SecondSectionItem *tappedItem = [self.secondSectionItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed;
    }

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
    [tableView endUpdates];

}
```

I've tried multiple approaches but none of them seem to work. I can't figure out what the problem is.

(I am new to objective C so some parts might seem a bit devious).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are initializing the UIImageView each time cellForRowAtIndexPath is running. But remember that that cells are reused so what you are doing is reusing a cell that has a checkmark and adding a new clear checkmark on top.

What you need to do is either:

1. Add the imageView in the storyboard, tag it, and user the tag to find it in the code
2. Subclass UITableViewCell and assign the correct image in there.

There are MANY articles of how to do both online.